# Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas not working with column that is object dtype

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to select all rows in pandas data frame where a certain condition is satisfied. I am trying the following way -

```
df.loc[df['column_name'] == some_value]
```

The column is an object data type. However the statement does not work all the time.For example if I try

```
df.loc[df['Reference'] == '0-1511-259102']
```

this works, but when I try

`df.loc[df['Reference'] == '4-4511-295542']`

this does not work even though I can see the value `'4-4511-295542'` in the dataframe from the variable explorer in spyder. It seems like all values which start with 0 work but all other values do not.

Does anyone know why this is ?

Comment: Maybe some trailing whitespaces problem? Then need `df['Reference'] = df['Reference'].str.strip()`

Comment: Thanks @jezrael it looks like it was white space problem the str.strip() has fixed it.